# How to cancel/abort a http request in middle of the process which uses postWithHeader function in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to stop uploading a video and some other http request if user presses back button on my UI.

Here are my functions which I call when I tap on submit button, which uploads video and the other submits the video and some data on the server:

`final http = HttpService();`

```
Future<bool> uploadAsset({
    required File asset,
    required int grpId,
    required int pId,
    required int rid,
  }) async {
    try {
      String? subD = SharedPrefs().subD;
      String? token = SharedPrefs().token;
      var res = await http.postWithHeader(subD,
          path: '$videoApi$rid/$grpId/$pId/assets',
          isMgmt: false,
          isActivity: true,
          body: FormData.fromMap({
            'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(asset.path),
          }),
          header: token);
      log(res.data.toString());
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        if (res.data['status_code'] == 200) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        log(res.data.toString());
        return false;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }
```

```
Future<bool> submitAsset({
    required int grpId,
    required int pId,
    required int rid,
  }) async {
    try {
      String? subD = SharedPrefs().subD;
      String? token = SharedPrefs().token;
      var res = await http.postWithHeader(subD,
          path: '$videoApi$rid/$grpId/$pId/submit',
          isMgmt: false,
          isActivity: true,
          body: {},
          header: token);
      log(res.data.toString());
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        if (res.data['status_code'] == 200) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        log(res.data.toString());
        return false;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I call these functions like this:

```
await ActivityServices()
                                .uploadAsset(
                                    rid: int.parse(widget.rid),
                                    grpId: widget.data.groupId!,
                                    pId: widget.data.userId!,
                                    asset: File(_media!.path))
                                .then((v2) async {
                              debugPrint("\n \n Asset Uploaded");
                              if (v2) {
                                await ActivityServices()
                                    .submitAsset(
                                  rid: int.parse(widget.rid),
                                  grpId: widget.data.groupId!,
                                  pId: widget.data.userId!,
                                )
```

Here is postWithHeader function:

```
Future<Response> _postWithHeader(
    String? subD, {
    required String path,
    required dynamic body,
    required String header,
    required bool xxxxx,
    required bool yyyyyy,
    bool? isFinance = false,
    Map<String, dynamic>? query,
  }) async {
    final _baseUrl = xxxxx
        ? mgmtBaseUrl
        : yyyyyyy
            ? xxxxxUrl()
            : xxxxxx!
                ? xxxxxxurl()
                : baseUrl(id: subD!);
    print(_baseUrl + path);
    try {
      late Response res;
      res = await _dio.request(_baseUrl + path,
          data: body,
          options: Options(
              method: 'POST',
              headers: xxxxx
                  ? {'tttt-ttt-ttttt': header}
                  : xxxxxx!
                      ? {
                          "xxxxxx": "xxxxxxxx",
                        }
                      : {
                          "xxxxx": "xxxxx xxxxx",
                          "xxxxxx": xxxxx(xx: xxxx!)
                        }),
          queryParameters: query);
      return res;
    } catch (e) {
      // showToast(e.toString());
      throw Exception(e);
    }
  }
```

I tried to understand this solution: [Dio Cancel current running API before starting a new API request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68887623/dio-cancel-current-running-api-before-starting-a-new-api-request), but couldn't. Can someone help me out with this?